# How do I create a new sheet with old data without taking the formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy data over into another sheet,creating like an archive of sorts but it is copying the formulas as well,making it a live sheet,instead of only taking the displayed data.

I looked around the web but none seems to answer what im looking for.
Most of the solutions only applies to CopyTo methods and {contentOnly:true} which didnt work for me.

```
function archiving() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var defectSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Total Defects'); 
  var ts = 'Archived_Total Defects '+ new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);

  ss.insertSheet(ts, ss.getSheets().length, {template: defectSheet});
}
```

Is does create the new sheet,but it takes all the information along with it,not just the displayed values.

Comment: Explain `didnt work for me.`

Comment: It came up as errors in the script when i tried to run it,such as cannot call,the other errors i dont remember them ,sorry...

Comment: Run it again, then view the Execution transcript, copy the transcript, and include it in your question.

Comment: I tested your code but added a `.copyTo()` method on the line after inserting the new sheet and it worked for me. What are the errors that you were receiving?

Comment: @AdrianPeh Look at [Creating a copy of a sheet by copying values only?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78257/196152). It is a more elegant and 100% working answer to your problem. I justed tested with demo data - 100% OK.

Comment: Thx @RafaGuillermo its working now. It only said cannot call (function) last fri,now there is no issues so... Thx for all your help

Comment: Thx @Tedinoz for helping to look it up and posting a sample as well. Thx for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 
`ss.insertSheet(ts, ss.getSheets().length, {template: defectSheet});`

You can run

```
var sheet = ss.insertSheet(ts, ss.getSheets().length, {template: defectSheet});
sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getDataRange(), {contentsOnly:true});
```

Which will copy the values of each cell to the new sheet rather than the formulae.